# What is the difference between Flat Style design and a Metro UI?

Tags: css, website-design, graphics

When I look at the two they look the same, only there's not that many named "Metro."  Is three a difference other than the name that Microsoft came up with?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there’s no difference. Microsoft had to change the name because “Metro” is a registered brand name of the [Metro AG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_AG).